# With Capybara + Poltergeist the data is not persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I'm using Capybara + Poltergeist and when I create an user in my scenario and show it in console, the user exists. When I ask to show in new session view, the `User.count` is 0.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: When I remove `js: true`, it works perfectly, but my page has ajax, then I need to use `js: true`

Comment: Fixed adding this:

`config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end`

Answer (score 0):

This may be because transactional fixtures are enabled.

Use database cleaner instead and disable them in the `RSpec.configure do |config|` block in your `rails_helper.rb`

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end
config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end
config.before(:each, js: true) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end
config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

You'll need to add

```
gem 'database_cleaner', :group => [:development, :test]
```

To you `Gemfile`